# How to organise .pem keys for AWS EC2 ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

How do I organize my .pem keys so that I dont have do this when logging in to AWS EC2:

```
ssh -i /home/user/mykey.pem ubuntu@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
ssh ubuntu@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I have tried putting the key in /home/user/.ssh and logging in like that, it did not work for some reason (Permission denied (publickey))....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create configuration entries in `~/.ssh/config` on your local machine, which is a file that isn't there by default.  Once you create it, it should be used automatically.

For each instance, declare it with `Host x.x.x.x`, add an `IdentityFile` entry with the path for the related key, and then optionally add `User ubuntu`.  Then all you need is `ssh x.x.x.x`.

See [`man ssh_config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).